# Reading AXSS (USR_ACCESS) register on a Xilinx Zynq-7000 Petalinux with FPGA Manager | No such file or directory error

Tags: fpga, xilinx, zynq, petalinux

I have a Xilinx ZC702 SoC board. PetaLinux 2020.1 running on it. I want to read the AXSS (USR_ACCESS) register from the FGPA. I set up the FPGA manager by using the `petalinux-config` commands. After compiling the kernel and rootfs, I load into the card.

The `fpgautil` user application is added as I can see from the console. I can run it, prompt help messages etc. But the problem is about the specific command as follows:

```
fpgautil -r
```

When I ran the above command from the PetaLinux terminal, I got the following error:

```
root@root:~# fpgautil -r
sh: /sys/module/zynqmp_fpga/parameters/readback_type: No such file or directory
cat: can't open '/sys/kernel/debug/fpga/fpga0/image': No such file or directory
Readback contents are stored in the file readback.bin
```

I follow the exact Xilinx tutorial in the link [Solution ZynqMP PL Programming](https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/18841847/Solution+ZynqMP+PL+Programming).

I did not understand why I got this error, furthermore, why `zynqmp_fpga` even if my SoC is not MPSoC but Zynq7000. Any help such as suggestions about roadmap or precise tutorial appreciated. Thanks :)